# how to run php script in a given specific time without using cron job and opening of the web page?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Basically I need a php script (which inserts some mysql queries into database at a particular specific time every day) runs without the cron job and without the opening of the page.

```
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$date_for_hold = date("Y-m-d");
$now = time();
$today = strtotime('18:41:00');

if (($today - $now) == 0) {
$refreshTime = $today - $now;
$update_query = "INSERT into rate values(NULL)";
$update = mysqli_query($conn, $update_query);
echo 'Working';
header("Refresh: $refreshTime; url=$page");
}

else{
echo 'Not Working';
}
```

I need this type of code without using ***cron jobs*** and without ***opening of the webpage*** also.

Comment: Use MySQL Events to call the script every x hours

Comment: Any alternate of cron? I don't want to open the script...

Comment: @Joaquin I have used MySql events but I have multiple queries from different tables to work on that script

Comment: _"Any alternate of cron? I don't want to open the script"_ - What you "want" shouldn't be what decides what to use. You should pick the right tool for the job. Is there a specific reason you don't want/can't use the best tool (cron) other than you "don't want to"?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson it is because my client don't want to use cron jobs, thats why I am looking for any alternate